# Problema ao exibir um form dentro de outro

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com problema ao exibir um form dentro de outro através de um panel.
A questão é que ao modificar o estado do form principal de `WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal` para `WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized`, o form aberto no panel não segue o tamanho do form principal, ficando assim:

Form normal:

[image: formulário normal]

Form maximizado:

[image: formulário maximizado]

Outro problema é que ao passar o form principal de normal para maximizado com algum form aberto no panel, o form principal não preenche toda a tela, ficando assim:

[image: problema no form]

Código utilizado para abrir forms no panel:

```
public void AbrirFormulario(Type formType)
    {
        pnFormulários.Enabled = true;
        pnFormulários.Visible = true;
        this.SuspendLayout();

        if (btVoltarInicio.Enabled == false)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lstFormulario.Count; i++)
                {
                    lstFormulario[i].Close();
                    lstFormulario[i].Dispose();
                    lstFormulario[i] = null;
                }

                lstFormulario.Clear();

                Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                form.TopLevel = false;

                pnFormulários.Controls.Add(form);
                form.Show();

                lstFormulario.Add(form);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            this.ResumeLayout(true);
            btVoltarInicio.Enabled = true;
            btVoltarInicio.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Botão para abrir algum form:

```
private void btCadCategorias_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormulario(typeof(cadastro_categoria));
    }
```

Comment: Já tentou alterar a propriedade Anchor do panel? Em tese, se vc deixar com "Top, Bottom, Left, Right', o panel vai seguir o tamanho do Form principal.

Comment: @MarceloMonteiro - Já fiz isso, não funcionou, acho que o problema está no evento: AbrirFormulario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade [Control.Dock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) setada como [Dock.Fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) para preencher todo o espaçamento vazio.

Outra forma seria criar um [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) e utilizar [Ancoragem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx).